# C++ Lambda Callback - How to capture variables?

Tags: c++, user-interface, lambda

I have this class

```
typedef void(*callback)();

class Button : public Control
{
private:
    callback onClickCallback;

public:
    void bind(callback func)
    {
        onClickCallback = func;
    }

    void onClick()
    {
        onClickCallback();
    }
};
```

Button inherits Control which is mapped as a component in the Gui class.
The Gui class has a method which will call the onClick method of every component on the list. The onClick method callback is lambda expression

```
Gui gui;
gui.addControl<Button>(x, y, width, height).bind([] {
  MessageBox(NULL, "OK", "OK", 0);
  //How to capture gui
  //Eg add another button on click: 
  //gui.addControl<Button>(x, y, width, height);
});
```

Here is the gui class

```
class Gui
{
private:
    int index;
    std::unordered_multimap<int, Control*> controls;

public:
    template <typename T, typename ...Args>
    T& addControl(Args... args)
    {

        auto control = new T{ std::forward<Args>(args)... };
        std::pair<int, Control*> pair(index, control);
        controls.insert(pair);
        index++;

        return *control;
    }

    void processMessages()
    {
        for (auto it = controls.begin(); it != controls.end(); ++it)
        {
            it->second->onClick();
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: You can't convert a lambda with capture to a function pointer. You need to change the type of callback to something it can be converted to.

Comment: Completely unclear what do you need to capture. Is your question about general capture syntax, or are you unclear about a particular case? If it is the former, you need to refere to the documentation, if the latter, post clearer code.

Comment: @Holt, non-capturing lambdas can be converted to function pointers.

Comment: @SergeyA Yes sorry, I was targeting this particular example which ask for capturing lambda.

Comment: Can you modify the `Button` class or does it comes from some external library?

Comment: @SergeyA i'm still trying to understand callback functions and lambdas so pardon my ignorance. I updated the question and included the Gui class code.

Comment: @Holt yes i can i forgot to note that im using the win32 api and i'm trying to create an object oritented approach of placing controls for my custom 3D editor.

Comment: I do not like the overall design. You are capturing the same object which is your container of elements. That doesn't seem right.

Comment: @SergeyA I'm concerned about that too. Originally i was going to ask if this is a good design but changed my question to the specific problem :D

Answer (score 0):

I actually did it, i don't know if this is the right solution but it seems to work.

Updated the Button class.

```
class Button : public Control
{
private:
    std::function<void()> onClickCallback;

public:
    //Override
    void bind(std::function<void()> func)
    {
        onClickCallback = func;
    }

    //Override
    void onClick()
    {
        onClickCallback();
    }
};
```

It works now !
Also added support for different events eg mouse_click, on_focus_gained etc...

```
gui.addControl<Button>(hWnd, "Button", 3, 26, 70, 23).bind("mouse_click", [&] {
    gui.getControl<Button>(0).setText("Clicked");
});
```